# Unity3d - Error Building Player: Win32Exception

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

Something happened in Unity that has never happened to me before, I have no scripting errors, everything is fine and dandy, but I get an error trying to build the final game.

Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\javac.exe', CommandLine='-bootclasspath "D:/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platforms/android-22\android.jar" -d "C:\Users\Zachery\Documents\Langsung\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "com\facebook\android\R.java" "com\NullReality\Relentless\R.java"', CurrentDirectory='C:\Users\Zachery\Documents\Langsung\Temp\StagingArea\gen'

This is the error I am getting, I have already done some research, and I tried Copying "zipalign.exe" from Build-Tools to "Tools" in the official Android SDK folder, and people are saying it worked for them, but not for me. I hope I am not one of those special people that have an error and although you fix it, it is still an error.

Please, help! I need to show my game off to some important people tomorrow, and if I can't fix this, I could lose my chance to get my game noticed!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try reinstalling Java JDK/JRE?